# I Want To implement checkboxes to run dynamically and take multiple inputs

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

**Model::**

```html
public function vendor_services($id)
  {
   $q=$this->db->where(['id'=>$id])
                ->get('vendor_services');
  return $q->result();    
  }
  public function add_vendor_services($id,$service)
  {
   $query = $this->db->get('vendor_services');

            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
             $ids[]=$row->id;
            }
           foreach($ids as $vid){
   if($id==$vid){
    $q1 =$this->db->get_where('vendor_services',array('id'=>$vid));
    $serv=$q1->row()->service_offered;
    if($serv===$service)
     return;
    else{
  $this->db->set('id',$id)
           ->set('service_offered',$service)
           ->insert('vendor_services');
   return;
   }}else{$this->db->set('id',$id)
           ->set('service_offered',$service)
           ->insert('vendor_services');
     return;
     }
  }
  }
  {
      $q =$this->db->get_where('services_list',array('id'=>$id));
         if($q->num_rows())
   {
    
    return $q->row()->name;
   }
   else{ return FALSE; }
   
  }
```

**

```html
$vendor=$this->input->post();
  $service_id=$this->input->post('service');
  unset($vendor['service']);
     $loc_id=$this->input->post('locations');
     $login_email=$this->session->userdata('email_id');
  $vendor['locations']=$this->Vendormodel->get_location($loc_id);
     $this->Vendormodel->add_vendor_profile($login_email,$vendor);
  $id1=$this->Vendormodel->get_vendor_id($login_email);
   if(isset($service_id))
  foreach($service_id as $id){
  $post[]=$this->Vendormodel->get_services($id);
  }
  if(isset($service_id))
  foreach($post as $service){
  $this->Vendormodel->add_vendor_services($id1,$service);
  }
  $vendordash['det']=$this->Vendormodel->vendor_details($login_email);
  $vendordash['services']=$this->Vendormodel->vendor_services($id1);
  $this->load->view('vendor/vendor_dashboard',$vendordash);
```

**

```html
<div class="container">
                            <label>Service Offering</label>
       <?php if(isset($services)) 
         foreach($services as $service): ?>
        <div style="width:20%; float:left;">
           <div class="checkbox"><label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="1" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Engineering and Design")echo "checked";?> >Engineering and Design</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"><label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="2"  <?php if($service->service_offered==="Operations and support")echo "checked";?> >Operations and support</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="3" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Product management")echo "checked";?> >Product management</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="4" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Developer relations and technical solutions")echo "checked";?> >Developer relations and technical solutions</label></div>
           <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="5" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Sales and account management")echo "checked";?>  >Sales and account management</label></div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:20%; float:left;">
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="6" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Partnerships")echo "checked";?> >Partnerships</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="7" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Sales and operations")echo "checked";?>  >Sales and operations</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="8" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Administrative services")echo "checked";?>  >Administrative services</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="9" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Business strategy planning")echo "checked";?>  >Business strategy planning</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="10" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Finance solutions")echo "checked";?>  >Finance solutions</label></div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:20%; float:left;">
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="11"  <?php if($service->service_offered==="Legal and government relations")echo "checked";?> >Legal and government relations</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="12" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Marketing and communications")echo "checked";?> >Marketing and communications</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="13" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Real estate and workplace services")echo "checked";?> >Real estate and workplace services</label></div>
           <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="14" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Social impact solutions")echo "checked";?> >Social impact solutions</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="15" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Consultancy services")echo "checked";?> >Consultancy services</label></div>
        <div class="checkbox"> <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name='service[]' value="16" <?php if($service->service_offered==="Investors and funding")echo "checked";?> >Investors and funding</label></div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
                            
                        </div>
```

**strong text**
This is my view page i want to take multiple inputs from controller and implement in checkboxes.....When i put more than one check the page shows another repeated list of all the checkboxes....no. of list shown=no. of inputs which is awkward............help me to make it run the way it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_array=array('1'=>'Engineering and Design','2'=>'Operations and support'.....);
```

set key value from 1 because your value look like that

assume that here this array key is going to set value for checkbox

store your value like this in array

use `array_search`

The `array_search()` function search an array for a value and returns the key.

```
<?php if(isset($services)) 
 foreach($services as $service): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name='service[]'  <?php if($key = array_search($service->service_offered, $new_array)){ echo "checked"; ?> value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php } else { echo 'value=""'; }   ?> ><?php echo $new_array[$key]; ?> <br/>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**EDIT:**

loop the $new_array like this

```
        <?php if(isset($new_array)) 
         foreach($new_array as $key=>$val): ?>

        if($db_key = array_search($val, $services))
         { 
            <input type="checkbox" name='service[]'    value="<?php echo $key ?>" checked ><?php echo $val; ?> <br/>
         }
         else
         {

           <input type="checkbox" name='service[]'    value="<?php echo $key ?>" ><?php echo $val; ?><br/>
         }

  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
public function vendor_services($id)
    {
        $q=$this->db->where(['id'=>$id])
                     ->get('vendor_services');
    return $q->result_array();      
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   //here fetch the value as array   
    }
```

Comment: can i initialize $new_array in the view file above the if statement??????

Comment: yeah you can initialize

Comment: did you understand the logic here ? what i am did ? @PratikAgarwal

Comment: yupp......but here i wil not whole list of checkboxes if not checked......i applied this code....and in result only the checked fields are being shown...but i want the non-checked values also so that it can be updated later if necessary....

Comment: now i got it what you want wait a minute .i am working for that

Comment: not working..........all the checkboxes are unchecked after checking also

Comment: here problem is $services is not array it is object .so can you fetch the $services as array @PratikAgarwal

Comment: look my edit2 and try and let me know @PratikAgarwal

Comment: using print_r i checked services is fetched as an array only then too all boxes are unchecked

Comment: if($db_key = array_search('Engineering and Design', $services))
         {  ECHO "hiIII"; }     TRY THIS DIRECTLY

Comment: ya this line is present

Comment: PRINT_R($services); AND KNOW THAT IS THERE HAVE 'Engineering and Design' IN THAT ARRAY

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [service_offered] => Engineering and Design )           print_r is showing this

Comment: OP its not array this is object .you have to fetch this one as array

Comment: in your model change result_array(); where from your getting the these $services list .

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [service_offered] => Engineering and Design ) [1] => Array ( [service_offered] => Product management ) ).................now showing like this but still not working

Comment: $services = array_column($services, 'service_offered');  do this and use the $services array

Comment: <?php if(isset($new_array))  $services = array_column($services, 'service_offered');    place it here

Comment: partially working....................engineering and design is not checked...........but product management is checked...    :)

Comment: so logic is correct may in your value have space in database or build array mismatch by space like this small issue look into that

Comment: var_dump($new_array) and var_dump($services)  and know the what difference there

Comment: 0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'service_offered' => string 'Engineering and Design' (length=22)

Comment: 1 => string 'Engineering and Design' (length=22)

Comment: but i cant find difference

Comment: 1st one is services 2nd is new_array

Comment: for testing use trim function if($db_key = array_search(trim($val), $services))

Comment: i think minor issue

Comment: nope that engineering and design is not checked in any case

Comment: oh okay .i will try

Comment: when i am doin print_r($val) in true section of if.....engineering and design is notshowing up...its showing up in else part